# Render certain words/characters in text input

Tags: javascript, html

When displaying strings in an HTML Text Input or TextArea I would like certain substrings to render with a box around them. Ideally those substrings would then be treated as a single entity rather than individual characters or indeed the stackoverflow tags below. Rather like highlighting or text emphasis but maybe with graphics.

For example:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------|
|                      _______                               |
| This string contains |boxed| characters within a textarea. |
|                      -------                               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please note that I want to mix text and tags - not just display tags.

Comment: You could contain the specific word in a tag and then style it accordingly. `border*` properties may be useful.

Comment: @mmontoya Is there a tutorial on how to begin? I don't even know where to start looking for how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with a textarea. A workaround could be emulate this behaviour by using a div with a `contenteditable=true` attribute on it, then you can apply the needed style.

You can check docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content.

Comment: Where is the `<textarea>`?

Comment: Much better. :)